# Latex for M, m use in the context for major and minor arc

Tags: fonts, characters

How can we write these "M" here in Latex? especially Overleaf?

[image][image]

Comment: Probably `\mathfrak{M} `

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned @daleif in his comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath} % or other fonts which contain fraktur font 
                                  % see https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/fraktur/

\begin{document}
$\mathfrak{m}$  $\mathfrak{M}$
\end{document}
```

[image]